# I have a model named 'module', and rake db:seed is failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model named 'module', how can I get this to work as it seems to be clashing with the reserved keyword.

My seeds.rb looks like:

```
module1 = Module.create(
...
)
module1.save!
```

I am trying to prefix my model like:

```
module ABC
  class Module < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Not sure how to fix this, do I do a require?  (I tried but it didn't work in my seeds.rb file):

```
require 'ABC'

module1 = ABC::Module.create(...)
```

*This is an existing table and I can't rename it in case someone suggests this.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to rename your table. Just rename the model and set the table name explicitly

Rails >= 3.2

```
class DbModule < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'modules'
end
```

Rails < 3.2

```
class DbModule < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.set_table_name 'modules'
end
```